# How to create editable field in PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext

1) First I tried following.Below code is creates second column of the table editable,however I want to have values of myVO.getClientAuthorized() and myVO.getClientSize() also in second column in respective two rows,but with following code I am not getting any value in second column.

```
public PdfPTable createTable(MyVO myVO){
            PdfPTable table = null;

            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            PdfPCell cell;
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    myVO.getClientAuthorizedLbl()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(myVO
                    .getClientAuthorized()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    myVO.getClientSizeLbl()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(myVO
                    .getClientSize()));
            table.addCell(cell);

            return table;
}


class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
        protected String fieldname;
        public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
        }

        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle,
                PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
            final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle,
                    fieldname);
            try {
                final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
                writer.addAnnotation(field);
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
            } catch (final DocumentException de) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Then I changed code to below.Basically I replaced

```
cell = new PdfPCell(); 
with 
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myVO.getClientAuthorized())); 
and second cell = new PdfPCell(); 
with 
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myVO.getClientSize()));

below is changed code :

public PdfPTable createTable(MyVO myVO){
            PdfPTable table = null;

            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            PdfPCell cell;
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    myVO.getClientAuthorizedLbl()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myVO.getClientAuthorized()));
            cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(myVO
                    .getClientAuthorized()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    myVO.getClientSizeLbl()));
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myVO
                    .getClientSize()));
            cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(myVO
                    .getClientSize()));
            table.addCell(cell);

            return table;
}


class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
        protected String fieldname;
        public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
        }

        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle,
                PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
            final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle,
                    fieldname);
            try {
                final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
                writer.addAnnotation(field);
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
            } catch (final DocumentException de) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
            }

        }
    }
```

Now I am getting text in second column,but it is no more editable.
Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my above question.

I added following code in cellLayout() method.

```
textField.setText(textField.getFieldName());
```

So complete cellLayout() method ow looks like as below :

```
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle,
                PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
            final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle,
                    fieldname);
            textField.setText(textField.getFieldName());
            try {
                final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
                writer.addAnnotation(field);
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
            } catch (final DocumentException de) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
            }
        }
```

With this,I can see text in the generated PDF and I can edit it as well.